# Choppy YouTube in Windows 11 in Hyper-V on Windows 11

Tags: video, windows-11, hyper-v, youtube

I'm connecting to a Windows 11 Pro VM using Hyper-V Manager on Windows 11 Pro. It seems to use RDP, but my YouTube playback is pretty bad compared to play on the host Windows 11.

The host has i7 12700K with 32GB RAM, and no dedicated GPU. The performance seemed to improve when num of v-cores was bumped from 2 to 12, but the playback of full HD or 4k video is nowhere near fluid as it is when played directly on host.

I'm thinking of reducing my electricity bill/footprint by moving a couple of small VMs from my home server into this host, and moving my Windows desktop into a VM, but this doesn't seem like a worthwhile venture if I can't even get videos to run smoothly inside Hyper-V.

Comment: The problem likely had to do with the face your not using VT-d. I hope you understand DX and OpenGL support is limited to specific versions with Hypervisors like Hyper-V

Comment: In addition to Ramhound’s comments, make sure your disk is a fast NVMe drive and consider using VMware Workstation. My Ubuntu guest runs YouTube content just fine

Comment: @Ramhound VT-d is enabled in BIOS, but I'm not sure how much YouTube player depends on GPU, and since my GPU is CPU integrated, that could pose a problem.

Comment: @steakoverflow - Your browser uses hardware acceleration to improve the performance of video playback on YouTube.  While VT-d is enabled you don't actually have any hardware that you can make accessible to the VM.